# how to check if the number that is in my list is odd

Tags: r

```
J
$nome
[1] "Mario"

$genere
[1] "maschio"

$età
[1] 50

$fratelli
[1] "Giorgio"

$num
[1] 505050
```

the $num is my number. It' class(J) list obv. Ty

i d k what i have to do
without IF function because i didn't do it already

Comment: Generally `x %% 2` will equal 1 if `x` is odd and `0` when `x` is even. So `x %% 2 == 1` will be TRUE when `x` is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions from the `apply` family to iterate over your list and if the element is numeric test if it's odd using the modulo operator `%%`. This operator returns the remainder after dividing by 2:

```r
J <- list(
  nome = "Mario",
  genere = "maschio",
  età = 50,
  fratelli = "Giorgio",
  num = 505050
)

isOdd <- \(x) if (is.numeric(x)) isTRUE(all.equal(x %% 2, 1)) else FALSE
sapply(J, isOdd)
#     nome   genere      età fratelli      num 
#    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
```

If the element is numeric it will test if it is odd and return `TRUE`/`FALSE`. If the element is not numeric it will return `FALSE`.